# takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, flask

Код

```
@app.route('/')
def parse(ip):
        theurl = 'http://%s/requests/status.xml' % ip
        username = ''
        password = ''
        passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)
        authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(theurl)
        doc = minidom.parse(pagehandle)
        full = doc.getElementsByTagName("fullscreen")
        vol = doc.getElementsByTagName("volume")
        fullscreen = full[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        volume  = vol[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        return "fullscreen: %s Volume: %s" % (fullscreen,volume)

def index():
        parse(ip='значение')
```

При выполнение выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: parse() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, значение вроде передал

Comment: Из за декоратора `@app.route('/')` наверное, почитайте про них

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`route('/')`  не содержит никаких параметров, поэтому при посещении `/` пути происходит вызов `parse()` без параметров также, что ведёт к `TypeError`.

Если хочется делать запросы вида `http://ваш сервис/a.example.com`, то необходимо [явно параметр указать используя `<имя параметра>` синтакс](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#variable-rules).
Вот полный пример web-приложения:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import requests # $ pip install requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify # $ pip install flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults=dict(host='example.com'))
@app.route('/<host>')
def make_request(host):
    url = 'http://{host}/requests/status.xml'.format(**vars())
    r = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'password'))
    doc = etree.fromstring(r.text)
    return jsonify(fullscreen=doc.findtext('.//fullscreen').strip(),
                   volume=doc.findtext('.//volume').strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost')
```

Если хост не указан, то используется `example.com` по умолчанию в этом примере.

Чтобы установить зависимости и запустить сервер:

```py
$ python -m pip install requests flask # install dependencies
$ python сервер.py                     # start http server
```

Чтобы открыть ccылку в браузере:

```py
$ python -m webbrowser http://localhost:5000/b.example.com # open browser
```

Comment: Спасибо Ваш пример очень хороший, но тут столкнулся с проблемой когда пытаюсь получить значения после парсинга, а именно "'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position" , пробовал encode('utf-8'), подскажите куда купать ? (Да, в тексте есть русский слова)

Comment: @santer: код работает с русскими словами (с любыми Юникодными символами на самом деле). Чтобы понять в чём проблема: [создайте *минимальный*, но полный пример кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который её демонструрует, опишите желаемое поведение словами, опишите что происходит вместо этого по-шагово, если есть сообщения об ошибках, то привидите *полный* traceback, укажите ОСь, версию Питона и опубликуйте всё вместе как отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

А что у Вас делает декоратор??? `@app.route('/')`
 Скорее всего из-за него.

**UPD**

попробуйте вместо `@app.route('/')`:

- `@app.route('/', {'ip' : 'передаете IP'})`

или

- `@app.route('/', ip='передаете IP')`

в общем вот: [ссылка](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/) там ищите на странице описание `app.route`

П.С. Спасибо за отличный комментарий - **OlegUP**

Comment: я использую фласк, таким образом он указывает роут

Comment: попробуйте вместо `@app.route('/')` - `@app.route('/', {'ip' : 'откуда то берете IP'})` или `@app.route('/', ip='откуда то берете IP')` в общемб вот: [ссылка](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/) там ищите на странице описание app.route